# Constantly writing to the Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, audio-streaming

I'm using Redux with React.js. I'm creating a client application for my API, it's an audio platform service. So naturally I need a player for my app, but I have absolutely no idea how to go about it as I will have to:

- Write to the store every time the time of a current track updates
- Be able to control the player anywhere in the application
- The player must be global

So, when you're using Redux, you can easily access data anywhere in your app with either `Store.getState()` or `@connect` in react.js. But since I am working with realtime audio here, wouldn't it be very memory inefficient to constantly update the store everytime the current time of a track changes?

Is it possible to do this with a simple global javascript object that I can just import?

I know that Redux store is immutable, so writing to it would save an old copy of the state, so doing this every 200ms is going to create problems, no?

Comment: Based on what you are saying here, no I don't think you will have "memory" problems.  Not sure why this would have anything to do with memory.  Anyway, the performance will probably be alright as well as all you would be doing is counting up time every 200ms.  The best way to know is to build a small POC and actually see if it works for you.

Comment: @DavinTryon Forgive me for asking, but what does POC mean? And are you sure writing to the store 200ms for each time the track currentTime updates is ok? My friend (who also works with react-native) says that it will eat up memory.

Comment: POC == Proof of Concept. :) Ask your friend how updating the same piece of state will eat memory.  Redux does not keep old copies of the store.  Only the Redux Dev Tools do that AFAIK.

Comment: @DavinTryon Thank you for your input, would using a simple javascript object with methods and variables (that dispatch to the store on events, etc and listen to the store) work? Or would it be better to make a react.js component? I'm sure you can do it however you want but I want to make sure I don't choose a bad method so that I get technological debt later on.

Comment: essentially, redux *is* just a simple javascript object that will handle dispatch events and update the component for you, so I'm not sure what rolling your own will give you.  If I were you, I'd probably build an audio player component that managed its own state (at first) for the timecode.

Comment: @DavinTryon Okay, so making a simple react component that lives in the root of my application would work fine? Any component inside my app will have to be able to get information from the player. :)

Comment: The player will raise events that can be reduces differently in parts of the state tree.  Other components can raise events that the player's state reduces.  You can have more than one reducer that handles events.